# AWS RDS out of memory error when adding column

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, innodb, amazon-rds

We got MySQL database on AWS RDS with innodb engine, the MySQL version is 5.6.19.

When trying to add a column in a table, we get the error message below:

**ERROR 1041 (HY000): Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space**

The script we run to alter table is below:
ALTER TABLE `mytablename` ADD COLUMN temp_colume varchar(255) NULL AFTER temp_firstcolumn;

Our RDS is on db.m3.2xlarge with 30GB memory:
Our innodb buffer size is DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4 ~= 24GB

We can successfully re-creating the table with the column changes already made to it, but we are getting error when altering tables.

Does anyone meet the same issue?

Comment: Is there possibly a lot of updates on the table while you're doing the `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: I also checked the SHOW PROCESS LIST which shows the DB is not busy

Comment: How about `ulimit -a` from the process that starts the MySQL daemon?  Did you look at the memory usage as it was processing, before it failed?

Comment: If you did not change any settings in my.cnf, you should write a bug with RDS, claiming that their default settings can lead to "out of memory".

Answer (score 7):

I've seen inplace alters in RDS fail lately. 
AWS support recommended modifying the alter table statement to look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN abc varchar(123) AFTER zyx, ALGORITHM=COPY
```

The secret is to add

```
, ALGORITHM=COPY
```

to the end as a work around.

You could also failover the RDS instance
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 2):

The error was fixed by simply rebooting our RDS. After rebooting, the memory increases 1.5 GB, we were have freeable memory ~ 3.5 GB, and now it is nearly ~5 GB. I am guessing the RDS itself (OS) cached some of the memory, but still a bit confused that why it gave error message when having 3.5 GB free memory and the table we tried to alter that was just 16KB.

Also, I find another similar issue. The link is below:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74432/mysql-rds-instance-eating-up-memory-and-swapping

Comment: This answer worked for me. But what i didnt understand is AWS show memory , or its percentage below par. I mean there was enough memory. And my table was also not that big.Then why giving this error.